# error update jsp mvc jdbc mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp, model-view-controller, jdbc

this file makes the connection with mysql

```
package Modelo;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Conexion {
Connection cnn;
Statement state;
ResultSet res;


public Conexion(){
try{
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); //driver
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){
Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
try{
cnn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/universidad3", "root", "uts");

} catch(SQLException ex){
Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
} // solo conexion
}

public ArrayList<Persona> consultarTodo(){
ArrayList<Persona> personas= new ArrayList<Persona>();
try{
String query="select * from persona";
state= cnn.createStatement();
res= state.executeQuery(query);
while(res.next()){
personas.add(new Persona(res.getString("rut"),res.getString("nombre"),   res.getInt("edad")));
}
return personas;
} catch(SQLException ex){
Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
}
 return personas;
}

public int insertar(Persona p){
int bandera=0;
try{
String query= "insert into persona(rut, nombre, edad)"+"values ('"+p.getRut()+"','"+p.getNombre()+"',"+p.getEdad()+")";
try{
state=cnn.createStatement();
} catch(SQLException ex){
Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

}
bandera=state.executeUpdate(query);

} catch(SQLException ex){
Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return bandera;
}

public boolean eliminar(String r){
try{
String query= "delete from persona where rut='"+r+"' ";
int saber=0;
state = cnn.createStatement();
saber = state.executeUpdate(query);
if (saber==1){
return true;
}

} catch(SQLException ex){
Logger.getLogger(Persona.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
}
return false;
}

public int editar(Persona p){
int bandera=0;
try{
String query= "(update persona set rut=?, nombre=?, edad=?)"+"values ('"+p.getRut()+"','"+p.getNombre()+"',"+p.getEdad()+")";
try{
state=cnn.createStatement();
} catch(SQLException ex){
Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

}
bandera=state.executeUpdate(query);

} catch(SQLException ex){
Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
return bandera;
}

}
```

this is the servlet file that does the update

```
package Controlador;

import Modelo.Conexion;
import Modelo.Persona;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class Editar extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   String rut = request.getParameter("txtRut");
    String nombre = request.getParameter("txtNombre");
    String edad = request.getParameter("txtEdad");
    int e = 0;
    try {
        e= Integer.parseInt(edad);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
    String error="Ingresar solo Numeros...";
    request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);    
    }
    Persona p1= new Persona(rut,nombre,e);

    Conexion cn= new Conexion();

     if(cn.insertar(p1) >0){
        String mensaje="Persona editada exitosamente..";
        request.getSession().setAttribute("mensaje", mensaje);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("exito.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    else{
        String error="No se puedo registrar...";
        request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}
```

when I tried to run the project I get the following errors:

> C:\Users\x2010s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MVCMySQL\src\java\Controlador\Editar.java:73:
>   error: class, interface, or enum expected
>       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
>   C:\Users\x2010s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MVCMySQL\src\java\Controlador\Editar.java:76:
>   error: class, interface, or enum expected
>       } C:\Users\x2010s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MVCMySQL\src\java\Controlador\Editar.java:87:
>   error: class, interface, or enum expected
>       protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
>   C:\Users\x2010s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MVCMySQL\src\java\Controlador\Editar.java:90:
>   error: class, interface, or enum expected
>       } C:\Users\x2010s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MVCMySQL\src\java\Controlador\Editar.java:98:
>   error: class, interface, or enum expected
>       public String getServletInfo() { C:\Users\x2010s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MVCMySQL\src\java\Controlador\Editar.java:100:
>   error: class, interface, or enum expected
>       }//  6 errors C:\Users\x2010s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MVCMySQL\nbproject\build-impl.xml:874:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\x2010s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MVCMySQL\nbproject\build-impl.xml:296:
>   Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details. BUILD
>   FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: Show the details of the  Internal Server Error type Exception .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the compiler error message carfully. It seems that before the method doGet there is a '}' too much.

I suggest you using a sophistcated IDE like eclipse which shows you such errors directly in the editor, before you "run the project".

Comment: already quite a } that had of more, when it returned to run the project leaves in the browser:

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.2 logs.